# apply fisher test in a large dataset that join all contingency tables

Tags: r, function, loops

I have a dataset like this:

```
contingency_table<-tibble::tibble(

x1_not_happy = c(1,4),
x1_happy = c(19,31),
x2_not_happy = c(1,4),
x2_happy= c(19,28),
x3_not_happy=c(14,21),
X3_happy=c(0,9),
x4_not_happy=c(3,13),
X4_happy=c(17,22)
)
```

in fact, there are many other variables that come from a poll aplied in two different years.

Then, I apply a Fisher test in each 2X2 contingency matrix, using this code:

```
matrix1_prueba <- contingency_table[1:2,1:2]
matrix2_prueba<- contingency_table[1:2,3:4]

fisher1<-fisher.test(matrix1_prueba,alternative="two.sided",conf.level=0.9)
fisher2<-fisher.test(matrix2_prueba,alternative="two.sided",conf.level=0.9)
```

I would like to run this task using a short code by mean of a function or a loop. The output must be a vector with the p_values of each questions.

Thanks,

Frederick

Answer (score 0):

So this was a bit of fun to do. The main thing that you need to recognize is that you want *combinations* of your data. There are a number of functions in R that can do that for you. The main workhorse is `combn()` [Link](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/utils/html/combn.html)

So in the language of the problem, we want all combinations of your tibble taken 2 at a time [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18298825/how-to-obtain-all-combinations-of-the-columns-of-a-data-frame-taken-by-2)

From there, you just need to do some looping structure to get your tests to work, and extract the p-values from the object.

```
list_tables <- lapply(combn(contingency_table,2,simplify=F), fisher.test)
unlist(lapply(list_tables, `[`, 'p.value'))
```

This should produce your answer.

**EDIT**

Given the updated requirements for just adjacement data.frame columns, the following modifications should work.

```
full_list <- combn(contingency_table,2,simplify=F)
full_list <- full_list[sapply(
             full_list, function(x) all(startsWith(names(x), substr(names(x)[1], 1,2))))]

full_list <- lapply(full_list, fisher.test)
unlist(lapply(full_list, `[`, 'p.value'))
```

This is approximately the same code as before, but now we have to find the subsets of the data that have the same question prefix name. This only works if the prefixes are exactly the same (`X3 != x3`). I think this is a better solution than trying to work with column indexes, and without the guarantee of always being next to one another. The `sapply` code does just that. The final output should be what you need for the problem.

Comment: Thanks, it was very useful. The problem is that I get 28 p_values and and should be only four , becasue there are four questions.