# Looping in Dplyr

Tags: r, for-loop, dplyr, combn

My question refers to looping in Dplyr. I'm trying to determine the mean, count number and variance for DV1 for each unique combination of independent variables (IV1:IV5).  My data looks like this:

```
DV1     IV1     IV2     IV3     IV4  IV5
506.2   Male    Canada  alpha   low  Orange
418.7   Female  Canada  beta    mid  Orange
380.3   Male    Canada  alpha   high Red
347.3   Male    Canada  alpha   mid  Red
241.6   Female  UStates alpha   mid  Blue
223.7   Female  Canada  beta    low  Green
220.9   Male    Canada  alpha   low  Orange
201.1   Male    Canada  alpha   low  Red
193.8   Female  Canada  beta    mid  Green
179.7   Female  UStates beta    low  Orange
170.7   Male    UStates beta    mid  Blue
149.5   Male    UStates beta    low  Green
146.2   Male    Canada  beta    high Green
144.2   Female  UStates beta    mid  Red
141.5   Male    Canada  beta    high Blue
138.6   Male    Canada  beta    mid  Blue
137     Male    Canada  beta    low  Red
136     Female  UStates beta    mid  Orange
135.9   Female  UStates beta    low  Red
134.6   Male    UStates alpha   mid  Orange
129     Female  UStates beta    mid  Green
127.1   Female  UStates beta    low  Green
120.4   Male    UStates beta    low  Blue
119.3   Female  UStates beta    high Red
118.6   Female  Canada  alpha   low  Blue
116.2   Female  Canada  alpha   high Green
113.7   Male    UStates beta    high Green
112.9   Female  UStates beta    low  Green
112.6   Male    Canada  alpha   mid  Green
112.2   Male    Canada  alpha   mid  Orange
109     Female  Canada  beta    high Orange
108.1   Female  Canada  alpha   mid  Blue
99.1    Female  Canada  alpha   high Blue
95.6    Male    UStates beta    mid  Green
88.1    Male    Canada  alpha   high Blue
83.9    Female  Canada  beta    high Green
83.7    Male    Canada  alpha   low  Green
80.8    Male    Canada  alpha   high Orange
79.9    Female  UStates alpha   high Blue
78      Female  UStates alpha   mid  Red
76.3    Female  UStates alpha   low  Blue
74.1    Female  UStates beta    high Orange
65.7    Female  UStates beta    high Red
62.1    Male    UStates alpha   high Red
54.8    Male    Canada  beta    low  Blue
54      Male    UStates alpha   mid  Red
42.8    Female  UStates alpha   low  Red
39.6    Male    UStates alpha   high Orange
19.5    Male    UStates alpha   low  Orange
19.2    Female  Canada  alpha   mid  Green
```

Using Dplyr, I've been able to create this. I need the information available under descriptive statistics for every unique combination of IV1:IV5

```
mod1=data1 %>%                                           
  group_by(IV1)%>%  
  summarise(avg_banding=mean(DV1),             
            total.count=n(),                          
            variance=var(DV1)) %>%                 
  print(n=50)     
#Descriptive statistics for the entire group (required!)
sum(mod1$avg_banding) 
mean(mod1$avg_banding)
mean(mod1$total.count)
mod1_2=mod1[complete.cases(mod1),] 
sum(mod1_2$variance)
```

As you can probably tell, I have to do this for every possible combination...
(IV1) (IV1,IV2) (IV1,IV2,IV3) (IV2, IV3) etc. There are a lot of combinations and I'm wondering if there's an easier way to do this instead of plugging away for each one! I have tried using a for loop without success.

```
mod2=data1 %>%                                             
  group_by(IV2)%>%  
  summarise(avg_banding=mean(DV1),             
            total.count=n(),                          
            variance=var(DV1)) %>%                 
  print(n=50)     

sum(mod2$avg_banding) 
mean(mod2$avg_banding)
mean(mod2$total.count)
mod2_2=mod2[complete.cases(mod2),] 
sum(mod2_2$variance)
```

Any help is greatly appreciated folks! thanks!

Comment: Something like this may give you a starting point https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18298825/how-to-obtain-all-combinations-of-the-columns-of-a-data-frame-taken-by-2

Comment: Thanks friend. I saw that thread before posting my question. The problem with that one is that the combn only posts columns in combinations of 2. I need an answer that has ALL possible combinations. 

For example, IV1, IV1+IV2, IV2+IV3+IV4+IV5, IV3+IV4+IV5 etc. (amongst hundreds others)!  

I can absolutely use combn(names(data), 1,simplify=FALSE), followed by combn(names(data, 2, simplify = FALSE) etc. until I go from 1:5, but I'm hopeful there's an easier way.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this using `dplyr` and `tidyr`.  You get each combination of the input data frame, by using `crossing`, a `left_join` with your original data, then `group_by` and `summarize`. My sample is limited to 10 rows.  Remember next time to include a reproducible example that includes data easily entered into R by using `dput`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr) #For expand

data <- tibble::tribble(~DV1, ~IV1, ~IV2, ~IV3, ~IV4, ~IV5,
   506.2,   "Male",   "Canada",  "alpha",   "low", "Orange",
   418.7,   "Female", "Canada",  "beta",    "mid",  "Orange",
   380.3,   "Male",   "Canada",  "alpha",   "high", "Red",
   347.3,   "Male",   "Canada",  "alpha",   "mid",  "Red",
   241.6,   "Female", "UStates", "alpha",   "mid",  "Blue",
   223.7,   "Female", "Canada",  "beta",    "low",  "Green",
   220.9,   "Male",   "Canada",  "alpha",   "low",  "Orange",
   201.1,   "Male",   "Canada",  "alpha",   "low",  "Red",
   193.8,   "Female", "Canada",  "beta",    "mid",  "Green",
   179.7,   "Female", "UStates", "beta",    "low",  "Orange"
  )

expand(data, IV1,IV2, IV3, IV4, IV5) %>% 
  left_join(data) %>% 
  group_by(IV1, IV2, IV3, IV4, IV5) %>% 
  summarize(mean = mean(DV1, na.rm = TRUE),
            var = var(DV1, na.rm = TRUE),
            n = n())
```

Comment: Thank you! I'm very grateful!

Answer (score 1):

One approach may be to create a variable that records the different patterns. I recoded each column into a binary 0,1 format and then concatenated them.  The resulting variable, `pattern`, is a unique "code" for each combination.

```
df$male<-ifelse(df$IV1=="Male",1,0)
df$ustates<-ifelse(df$IV2=="UStates",1,0)
df$alpha<-ifelse(df$IV3=="alpha",1,0)
df$low<-ifelse(df$IV4=="low",1,0)
df$red<-ifelse(df$IV5=="red",1,0)


attach(df)
df$pattern<-paste(male,ustates,alpha,low,red) #concatenate into a "code"
library(psych)
describe.by(df$DV1,df$pattern)
```

Comment: why do you need to convert to numeric before concatenating?

Comment: Hi @BenBolker -->  I see your point, although the idea comes from an earlier analysis in which I also wanted a count of each row, so the recode to 0,1 was necessary. But you are right, the "code" could simply be concatenated strings.

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
library(HapEstXXR)
library(dplyr)

# Import the data
data1 = data.frame(DV1 = c(506.2,418.7,380.3,347.3,241.6,223.7,220.9,201.1,193.8,179.7,170.7,149.5,146.2,144.2,141.5,138.6,137,136,135.9)
                   , IV1 = c("Male","Female","Male","Male","Female","Female","Male","Male","Female","Female","Male","Male","Male","Female","Male","Male","Male","Female","Female")
                   , IV2 = c("Canada","Canada","Canada","Canada","UStates","Canada","Canada","Canada","Canada","UStates","UStates","UStates","Canada","UStates","Canada","Canada","Canada","UStates","UStates")
                   , IV3 = c("alpha","beta","alpha","alpha","alpha","beta","alpha","alpha","beta","beta","beta","beta","beta","beta","beta","beta","beta","beta","beta")
                   , IV4 = c("low","mid","high","mid","mid","low","low","low","mid","low","mid","low","high","mid","high","mid","low","mid","low")
                   , IV5 = c("Orange","Orange","Red","Red","Blue","Green","Orange","Red","Green","Orange","Blue","Green","Green","Red","Blue","Blue","Red","Orange","Red")
)

# Create a powerset of IV1, IV2, IV3, IV4, IV5
cols = c("IV1", "IV2", "IV3", "IV4", "IV5")
cols_combos = powerset(cols)

# Create an empty data frame to store the statistics in for each column combination
stats_df = data.frame()

# Function to calculate stats for a particular column combination
getStats = function(data1, stats_df, cols) {
  mod = data1 %>%
    group_by_(.dots = cols) %>%
    summarise(avg_banding=mean(DV1),
              total.count=n(),
              variance=var(DV1)) %>%
    mutate(COMBO = paste0(cols, collapse=",")) %>%
    group_by(COMBO) %>%
    summarise(sum_avg = sum(avg_banding)
              , avg_avg = mean(avg_banding)
              , avg_cnt = mean(total.count)) %>%
    ungroup() %>%
    select(COMBO, sum_avg, avg_avg, avg_cnt)

  stats_df = rbind(stats_df, mod)
  return(stats_df)
}

# Loop through column combinations to generate stats for each
for(col in cols_combos) {
  stats_df = getStats(data1, stats_df, col)
}
```

Requires the package HapEstXXR in order to create a powerset of all the column combinations. The results are stored in a dataframed called stats_df.

Comment: Hi Friend. Thank you so much for your help! The script works great. Just one additional question. At the very end, I'm getting a shortened table with #A tibble: [number here] x 4. The table has 10 combinations of IV1:IV5 and at the end of the table is "... with [number here] more rows. The COMBO gives 10 of the combinations (IV1, IV2, IV1+IV2, IV3 etc.). How would I go about getting the rest? I've tried this   for(col in cols_combos) {
  stats_df = getStats(data1, stats_df, col)
  print(stats_df)
}

Comment: Use the following command: View(stats_df) (capitalization of V matters). I would recommend downloading and using the RStudio IDE if you aren't already. It makes it easy to view data frames.